# Google Sheets COUNTIFS if cell contains part of text, exclude blanks

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am unsure of the use of COUNTIFS with two variables while excluding blank cells from being counted in this scenario, wanted to see if there would be a more viable solution. I am relatively new to Google Sheets, please forgive me if the question seems simple. For context, I have two worksheets:

Sheet1 contains Form Responses in the following columns:

A: Timestamp
B: Name
C: Food

In Sheet2 Column A, I have each possible answer that can appear in Sheet1 Column B. In the first row of Sheet2 starting in B1, I have each possible answer that can appear in Sheet1 Column C. These act as data headers. These are the headers of this table.

In the cells between them, I am using a COUNTIFS formula:

```
=COUNTIFS('Form Responses 1'!$B:$B,Sheet2!$A2, 'Form Responses 1'!$C:$C,"*"&Sheet2!$B$1&"*")
```

This formula checks the contents of cell A2 on Sheet2 against the values that may appear in Column B on Sheet1 and checks the contents of column C on Sheet1 against the cell contents of cell B1 on Sheet2 using an intentional * wildcard to count all cells in Sheet1 Column C that contain the text in Sheet2 B1.

My issue is that in Sheets, it seems to handle the exclusion of blank cells in a different way from Excel. Using methods outlined for similar uses, the addition of "<>" or ">""" would normally do the trick, but seems to fail to do so in Sheets.

I've read that DCOUNTA may be a more worthwhile route to take than COUNTIFS. Considering my intention with this formula, is there a variation of DCOUNTA that can handle multiple variables in the way COUNTIFS can?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=COUNTIFS('Form Responses 1'!$B:$B,Sheet2!$A2,'Form Responses 1'!$C:$C,"*"&Sheet2!B$1&"*")
```

(One fewer `$`.)

The `Sheet2!` are not required.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `"<>"` is a correct form of excluding blank cells in `countifs`. Example:

```
=countifs(C:C, ">2", D:D, "<6", E:E, "<>")
```

counts the rows where C is greater than 2, D is less than 6, and E is nonempty.

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm the weirdness of COUNTIFS.

In general in COUNTIFS, FILTER and similar formulas you can use any scalar function for the condition, using a range in place of the scalar argument. So in case of COUNTIFS and blanks, this should also count blanks:

```
=countifs(A:A, isblank(A:A))
```

But things start going south indeed when you start applying nested functions.

```
=countifs(A:A, not(isblank(A:A)))
```

does not work reliably for me... Perhaps because of the well known problem with Booleans inside array functions. But

```
=rows(filter(A:A, not(isblank(A:A))))
```

does work every time. Strange!