# AND in ARRAYFORMULA giving error

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm just getting myself confused here.

I have a `Planning` spreadsheet with people's name in A, their skills in C, and their status in I. I would like to create another sheet within this spreadsheet that contains just the rows where the skills contain the word `Java` and status contains `pending`. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this

```
=FILTER('Planning'!A2:L900, 
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    AND(
      ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Java", 'Planning'!C2:C900)),
      ISNUMBER(SEARCH("pending", 'Planning'!I2:I900)) )))
```

this doesn't seem to work erroring with

```
FILTER has mismatched range sizes
```

It seems that I'm using `AND` incorrectly as

```
=FILTER('Planning'!A2:L900, 
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Java", 'Planning'!C2:C900)) )))
```

works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach might be:

```
=query(Planning!A:L,"select * where C contains 'Java' and I contains 'pending' ")
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Though I'd still like to know why `AND` wasn't working above...

Comment: Boolean functions such as AND(), OR() and NOT() have known weird behaviors inside array contexts, too. It's a common practice to replace them with arithmetics. I.e. instead of AND(cond1, cond1) just try cond1*cond2. Also, wrapping them in ARRAYFORMULA seems to be unnecessary. The FILTER already provides an array context.

Comment: Hi @pnuts, I'm calling them weird because I have run into issues in the past that I cannot explain or find any documentation on. Examples: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/102470/google-sheets-countifs-if-cell-contains-part-of-text-exclude-blanks/105604#105604 or https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/U541KrM_Amg -- if you can help with explaining that, it would be great.

Comment: @pnuts I've basically given up on Excel, using it at most to share data via email... but from what I remember, array formulas work quite a bit differently there, and of course there is no FILTER(), UNIQUE(), QUERY() etc.  But I will give you just one example: OR(), AND() and NOT() do not work at all when applied inside an ARRAYFORMULA. I.e. they are not even expanded.  Try =arrayformula(or(A:A="TextA", A:A="TextB")) and then for comparison =arrayformula((A:A="TextA")+(A:A="TextB"))